# How to display alert message after submitting form

Tags: php

I want to display alert message of language selected. Disply alert message after submission of form.Below the code.I want to display alert message of language selected after.How can i do this?

```
  <?php
  global $mysqli;

  $lang="Select `prompt_language` FROM `account_detail` WHERE `org_id`='36'";
  $res= $mysqli->query($lang) or die($mysqli->error);
  $row=$res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

  if($_POST['submit']=="Save")
  {

  $language=$_POST['pbx_lan'];
  if($language!="")
  {


  $query="update `account_detail` set `prompt_language`= '$language' WHERE `org_id`='36'";
  $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error);

  $_SESSION['check_update'] = "1";
  setcookie("msg","Language Successfully Updated",time()+5,"/");
  header("location:".SITE_URL."index.php?view=view_service");

  }

  else
  {
  setcookie("err","No Language Selected.Please Select Language",time()+5,"/");
  header("location:".SITE_URL."index.php?view=view_service");
  }

  }
  ?>

  <div class="dashboard">
  <h2>Select  Language<h2>

  <form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="prompts.php" >
  <select id="pbx_lan" name="pbx_lan" style="margin-left:5px width=1px" class="input validdid required" >
  <option value="">Select</option>

  <option value="en" <?php echo $row['prompt_language'] == "en" ? "selected=selected" : ""; ?>>English</option>
  <option value="uk"  <?php echo $row['prompt_language'] == "uk" ? "selected=selected" : ""; ?>>English(UK)</option>

  </select><br></br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="sub" value="Save" class="btn" style="margin-left:5px" />
  </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: `echo "<script>alert('your message');</script>";`

Comment: not working.I add echo '<script>alert("You have selected '.$language.'")</script>';
header("location:".SITE_URL."index.php?view=view_service"); after if($language!="")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place try the below  code

```
echo '<script>
alert("You have selected '.$language.'");
window.location = "'.$SITE_URL.'index.php?view=view_service."
</script>';
//header("location:".SITE_URL."index.php?view=view_service");
```

Comment: not working.I add echo '<script>alert("You have selected '.$language.'")</script>'; header("location:".SITE_URL."index.php?view=view_service"); after if($language!="")

Comment: Place this code after  `setcookie("msg","Language Successfully Updated",time()+5,"/");`

Comment: Are you getting any err?

Comment: No.i am not getting any error.But alert box not come.I tried it replacing it but didn't work